# Gibt es eine deutsche Bezeichnung für "orange & teal"

Tags: single-word-request, technical-terminology

Ein aktuell einigermaßen beliebtes Farbschema in Film und Design nennt sich *[Orange and Teal](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104189/how-to-achieve-orange-and-teal-look-in-gimp)*, das sind Kompositionen aus Farbnuancen Orange und Blaugrün (= *teal*).

[image]
<sup>*Orange* und *Teal* in der HTML Farbnotation</sup>

Nun ist die englische Farbbezeichnung *[teal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names)* (x008080) im Deutschen kaum bekannt.

Die Farben *Türkis* [image] oder *Zyan* [image] sind streng genommen andere Farbtöne.

Das Mittelniederdeutsche *[telink](http://www.koeblergerhard.de/mnd/mnd_t.html)* ist offenbar verschwunden. Eine ansonsten naheliegende Übernahme des englischen Begriffs *orange and teal* erscheint deshalb problematisch.

Kennt jemand eine gebräuchliche deutsche Bezeichnung, und wenn nicht, was wäre ein ähnlich griffiger Begriff?

Comment: "Cyan/Orange" habe ich schon gesehen, "türkis/orange" auch.

Comment: Eine *korrekte* Bezeichnung würde ich hier gar nicht suchen. Denn wer wollte sagen, was korrekt ist. Man  kann aber sicherlich herausfinden, welche Bezeichnungen in bestimmten Kreisen (z.B. Berufsgruppen) *üblich* sind dafür. Da kommen ja v.a. Medienschaffende in Frage, gar nicht so sehr die Allgemeinheit. Meine Hypothese: Meidenschaffende tendieren zur Übernahme der englischen Bezeichnung, Normalbürger würden eher "Orange und Türkis" sagen (tun sie aber nicht, weil sie sich über solche Farbschemata selten unterhalten).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Genau darüber zu reden, ist bei Kinofilmen, wo diese "Südsee-Koloration" schon ziemlich überhand nimmt, gar nicht mehr so ungebräuchlich.

Comment: @tofro   "Südsee-Koloration" gefällt mir. Vielleicht wäre auch "Krebsgelb/Meerblau" eine schöne Variante. (Aber das war ja leider nicht die Frage.)

Comment: "Südsee-Koloration" ist mir zu despektierlich - das sagen bestimmt nur die Kritiker dieser Farbgebung - Kritik mag ja berechtigt sein, aber ich bin  auf der Suche nach einem neutralen Begriff. Türkis trifft die Farbe zwar nicht, aber wenn man (wo? gibt es eine Referenz?) es so sagt, meinetwegen.

Comment: da z.B. läßt sich jemand drüber aus https://community.sony.at/t5/entdecke-sony/geht-die-turkis-und-orange-besessenheit-beim-film-zu-weit/ba-p/1944087 "Südsee-Koloration" war meine (zugegebenermaßen abfällige) Bemerkung.

Comment: @tofro   Komisch, ich fand *Südsee-Koloration* überhaupt nicht despektierlich. Ich dachte eben an die typischen kitschigen Inselbilder und fand das sehr positiv besetzt.

Comment: Ähm. Google findet genau eine URL in einer Suche nach "Südsee-Koloration", nämlich diese Frage hier.

Comment: Die deutsche Sanitärindustrie bezeichnet  _teal_ klassicherweise als **Calypso**. Ich halte den Begriff für halbwegs etabliert.

Comment: @Takkat Ähm. Sagichdoch.

Comment: RAL 2000–2021 sind verschiedene Orange-Töne, die auch alle _orange_ im Namen tragen. Das gezeigte Teal ähnelt 5018 Türkisblau, 5021 Wasserblau, 6033 Minttürkis und 6034 Pastelltürkis. _Türkis_ scheint daher gar nicht so abwegig. In den englischen Namen der [RAL Classics](https://www.ral-farben.de/inhalt/anwendung-hilfe/alle-ral-farbnamen/uebersicht-ral-classic-farben.html) wird _teal_ nicht verwendet.

Comment: @scienceponder  - Guter HInweis, dass es in der Sanitärbranche diese Farbbezeichnung gibt. Aber andererseits, wenn ich mit Freunden über einen Film spreche und erzähle, er folge farblich dem Schema "Orange-Calypso", würde das keiner verstehen. (Es sei denn er wäre Fliesenleger, vielleicht?)

Comment: seegrün habe ich schon gehört dafür

Comment: Diese [Website](https://blog.patrickkempf.de/2004/html-farben/) nennt #008080 "entenbraun" (oder "teal")? Waaaas? Braun?

Comment: Hmmm... diese [Webseite](https://bfw.ac.at/020/farbtabelle.html) auch. Vielleicht hat einer vom anderen abgeschrieben?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: diesen Eintrag habe ich auch gesehen... *teal* ist alles andere als braun, das muss jemand geschrieben haben, der es nicht so mit Farben hat ;)

Comment: @Takkat Ich würde sagen der Frabton ist schicht als "blaugrün" oder,- wie berets erwäht-, "seegrün" bekannt.

Comment: Was hat es mit 'telink' auf sich? Die von dir verlinkte Website listet telink auf als 'Halbente' oder 'kleinere Ente'. War dieser Begriff jemals als Farbton gebräuchlich?

Comment: @shuhalo: *teal* stammt von *telink* ab: https://www.etymonline.com/word/teal und bedeutet [diese Ente](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Amazonetta_brasiliensis.jpg), von der der Farbname abstammt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Farbbezeichnungen sind im zwischensprachlichen Bereich oft die Strafe des Herrn für Übersetzer.

Allerdings glaube ich, dass ich hier tatsächlich helfen kann:
Soweit ich sehe, handelt es sich praktisch um den Farbton, der bei Kleidung seit einiger Zeit "**Petrol**" heißt.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyan#Verwandte_Farbnamen) scheint dies auch so zu sehen:

> Für dunkle Farbvarianten aus dem Cyan-Farbtonbereich 490 nm bis 500 nm
>   sind die Farbnamen Blaugrün oder Seegrün üblich, neuerdings auch die
>   englischen Bezeichnungen Petrol (Modebereich) und Teal (Webfarbe).

... oh, und LEO gibt ebenfalls "petrol" als Übersetzung (die Glaubwürdigkeit wird allerdings durch die ebenfalls gegebenen "aquamarin" und "smaragdgrün" relativiert ...

Auch wenn der Begriff im Medienbereich weniger üblich als "Teal" ist, werden also zumindest <s>weibliche</s> mode-affine Gesprächspartner wissen, was Du meinst, wenn Du "Orange und Petrol" erwähnst. :)

Comment: Wobei *"Orange und Petrol"* nun fast schon so Englisch ist wie *"Orange and Teal"*... aber wenigstens weiß man dann, welche Farbe gemeint ist ;)

Comment: @Takkat: Ah, die Englisch-Komponente bei "Petrol" ist mir noch gar nicht aufgefallen ... sooft ich den Begriff von deutschen Sprechern gehört habe, wurde er _Petról_ ausgesprochen, klingt also gar nicht mehr englisch.

Comment: Es gibt auch Entenblau (evtl. als Verlegenheitsübersetzung von "Teal"), aber da meine ich, dass das kaum jemand kennt oder benutzt, schon gar nicht in der Kombination "Orange und Entenblau".

Comment: @Takkat: Hmm, ziemlich deskriptiv -- aber gehört hab ich das auch noch nicht :)

Answer (score 0):

Entenblaú für teal. Teal ist die Bezeichnung für eine blau schimmernde Ente.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Ich selbst habe keine Ahnung von, daher meine Frage: gibt es eine weiterführende Quelle, die slche Farbennamen führt und sich hier anführen ließe? Und ist der Akzent über dem ersten u gewollt?

Answer (score -2):

Eingebürgert ist es sicherlich nicht, aber nach Lektüre der ausführlichen Kommentare oben schlage ich nun vor:

> Orange und Nacht-Türkis

Der Einwand, *teal* sei nicht typisches Türkis ist richtig. Mit *Nacht-Türkis* lenkt man die visuelle Vorstellung aber jedenfalls in die richtige Richtung. - Die Parallelbildung *Nachtblau* ist ja eingebürgert, da wird sich das deutsche Ohr vielleicht auch an *Nachttürkis* gewöhnen können.

**Experimentierfeld**

Etwas poetischer vielleicht noch

> Orange und Tiefseeblau

Comment: Dict.cc nennt das schlicht "grünblau". Aber das erklärt immer noch nicht das Konzept, den Terminus "orange & teal": die Hervorhebung der gelben und orangenen Farbtöne und die Verdunklung der grünen und blauen, um einen besseren Kontrast zu erwirken und vor allem Hautfarbe besser darzustellen und auch um Assoziationen mit, eben, Südsee-Farben und Strand/Haut in der Sonne zu wecken. Dafür gibt es m.E. keinen deutschen Begriff, obwohl Südsee-Koloration eigentlich ein guter Vorschlag wäre. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: ich habe ja auch keinen deutschen Begriff für eben dieses Konzept gefunden, bzw. reden Designer halt auch von *Orange & Teal*. Insofern wäre Dein Kommentar auch für eine Antwort geeignet, oder?